# When I enter password, I'm redirected to the WordPress login form

Tags: pages, users, password, wp-login-form

I have a page at `http://localhost/wix/dss/` when I enter, I get redirected to `http://localhost/wix/wp-login.php` with the error message

> Error: The password you entered for the username ak is incorrect.
> Lost your password?

Any ideas as to why that's happening? I'm at a loss.
Screenshot- https://prnt.sc/x6wvlr

```
<?php
 /* 
  * Template Name: Login Template Page
  */
get_header();  
?>  
<div class="login-branding">
  <p class="login-desc" style="">Login</p>
  <div class="login-form">
    <?php
     $args = array(
     'redirect' => home_url(), 
     'id_username'    => 'user_login',  
     'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
     );
    ?>
    <?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and turned them on 1 by 1 to check which one causes the problem? There is no code in your question to debug

Comment: I tested the password form and it submits to the place it is told to, passing all parameters - so - as Tom suggested - there is probably a plugin changing the way WP handles this submitted data that needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

First change password function to MD5 in `wp_users` table in database.

```
 <?php
 /* 
  * Template Name: Login Template Page
  */
 get_header();  
 ?>
<div class="login-branding">
  <p class="login-desc" style="">Login</p>

  <div class="login-form">
  <?php
  $args = array(
    'redirect' => home_url('/wix/dss'), 
    'id_username'    => 'user_login', 
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',   
  );
   ?>
   <?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed here please? At first glance it's just `home_url()` to `home_url('/wix/dss')`, which doesn't look right to me.

Comment: gave its path in home_url() and change password to encrypt

Comment: What is the encrypt change? It's not in this code, and I can't think which field you mean in the database.

Comment: in wp_users table and in column user_pass

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. change to md5 for password field